# jquery dynamic collapsible list doesnt work; jsfiddle example

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to create a `collapsible-set`. Each `collapsible` within that set contains a `ul-listview`. The problem arises when I need to dynamically add `collapsible` item to the `collapsbile-set`.

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
```

This is the jsfiddle for this program:

http://jsfiddle.net/ezuo3btc/15/

That's the initial html in the index page:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="d" id="set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="set1" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
            <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is called on the click event and adds, dynamically, a `collapsible` to the `collapsible-set` defined statically in the html:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    nextId++;
    var content = '\
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="set' + nextId + '">\
        <h3>Section ' + nextId + '</h3>\
        <ul id="listview' + nextId + '" data-role="listview">\
            <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>\
            <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>\
            <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>\
        </ul>\
    </div>';
    $("#set").append( content ).collapsibleset('refresh');
    $("[data-role=listview]").listview("refresh"); <--------- I get the error here.
    $("[data-role=listview]").trigger("create");
});
```

If someone knows how to initialize a listview dynamically inside a collapsible please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Jenia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call the "refresh" method the first time you call .listview():

```
    $("[data-role=listview]").listview();
    $("[data-role=listview]").trigger("create");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ezuo3btc/18/

Answer (score 1):

You need to first initialize the listview widget with `$element.listview();`:

```
$("[data-role=listview]").listview();
$("[data-role=listview]").listview("refresh"); //optional
```

---

Some recommendations:

- `$("[data-role=listview]")` applies on all elements with `data-role=listview`, even the previously created ones. Prefer something like this:

  ```
  var $content = $(content).appendTo($("#set"));
  $("#set").collapsibleset('refresh');
  $content.find("[data-role=listview]").listview();
  $content.find("[data-role=listview]").trigger("create");
  ```
- `$("#set")` always reference the same node, you can put it in a variable

  ```
  var $set = $("#set");
  ```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ezuo3btc/22/)